# Multiple else if with indexOf

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var aaaa = exploded[1];

if (aaaa.indexOf("bbbb")>=0) { //Do something Here }
```

Everything works great, but when i add:

```
else if (aaaa.indexOf("cccc")>=0) { //Do something Else }
else if (aaaa.indexOf("dddd")>=0) { //Do something Else 2 }
else if (aaaa.indexOf("eeee")>=0) { //Do something Else 3 }
```

I get a message "aaaa is undefined" and the code wont run. How can i fix this?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Commenting the curly braces was a mistake when i wrote here in Stacoverflow, it has nothing to do with my issue. I solved my issue removing a lost curly brace inside the first else if. Problem Solved!

Comment: You didn't really post enough code here.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to do `/* comment */` instead of `// comment` as you don't intend for the comment to continue until the EOL.

Comment: stop using notepad and use an editor which highlights silly semantic errors...

Answer (score 1):

You're breaking your code by not having the curly braces on a separate line - since you're using a single line comment, it's also commenting your last curly brace.

Change:

```
else if (aaaa.indexOf("cccc")>=0) { //Do something Else }
else if (aaaa.indexOf("dddd")>=0) { //Do something Else 2 }
else if (aaaa.indexOf("eeee")>=0) { //Do something Else 3 }
```

To:

```
else if (aaaa.indexOf("cccc")>=0) {
    //Do something Else
}
else if (aaaa.indexOf("dddd")>=0) {
    //Do something Else 2
}
else if (aaaa.indexOf("eeee")>=0) {
    //Do something Else 3
}
```

Other than that, everything looks fine.

Comment: You may want to clarify that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this change could make any difference. Also there are no semicolons in your answer :-)

Comment: @Pointy bah, i meant curly braces :P

Comment: @Xander but curly braces look same to me for both options, you just write them into two lines

Comment: @sachin, in his example he's commenting out the trailing curly brace. which is causing his code to break. given his code sample, that's the only thing that is incorrect.

Comment: ohh yes @Xander I just see it :)

Comment: That was a typo error writing here in Stackoverflow, but i solved the issue..it was a lost curly brace inside a "else if". Probably if i didint did typo error here in Stack, you all wont call me the attention of curly braces in my code!! :) I will edit the first post to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine:

```
var aaaa = "bbbb";

if (aaaa.indexOf("bbbb")>=0) { 
    alert('aa') ;
}
else if (aaaa.indexOf("cccc")>=0) { 
    alert('cc');
}
else if (aaaa.indexOf("dddd")>=0) { 
    alert('dd');
}
else if (aaaa.indexOf("eeee")>=0) { 
    alert('ee');
}
```